# Ошибка при создании пакета Debian: cannot create directory ‘/opt/simplest_studio’

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Пытаюсь создать пакет .deb.
Создал файлы control, rules, всё сделал,как было сказано в инструкции и после десятитысячной попытки всё равно вылазят ошибки.
Команда $(MAKE) выполняется удачно, создается бинарный файл, но потом происходит что-то непонятное: например, попытка в процессе команды '$(MAKE) install' создать директорию ‘/opt/simplest_studio’. Ничего не понимаю, откуда это берется. Т.е. вместо того, чтобы поместить бинарник в папку usr/bin, которую я указываю, сборщик зачем-то пытается установить его в папку 'opt'.
Потом не понятно как мне задать в файле rules установку иконки и ярлыка запуска приложения,
пытался найти примеры с установкой ярлыка и иконки, не могу найти...
Подскажите что со всем этим делать?

Вот вывод терминала с ошибкой:

```
helg@helg-VirtualBox:~/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot
.
.
/usr/bin/make install DESTDIR=/home/helg/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/helg/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/simplest_studio’: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1075: install_target] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/helg/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1'
make: *** [debian/rules:23: install] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
```

Файл мой файл 'rules':

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1

build:
    $(MAKE)
    #docbook-to-man debian/packagename.sgml > packagename.1

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp
    $(MAKE) clean
    dh_clean

install: build
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_prep
    dh_installdirs
    # Add here commands to install the package into debian/package
    $(MAKE) install DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin 

# Build architecture -independent files here.
# binary-indep: build install

# Build architecture -dependent files here.
binary-arch: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installexamples
    dh_install
    dh_installman
    dh_link
    dh_strip
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
    dh_installdeb
    dh_shlibdeps
    dh_gencontrol
    dh_md5sums
    dh_builddeb

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
.PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install configure
```

Comment: *Ничего не понимаю, откуда это берется* — как откуда? вы же сами написали: в `Makefile`, в строке 1075, в рецепте к правилу `install_target`

Comment: Да, действительно там 'opt', сейчас ищу способ как это автоматически заменить на 'usr/bin'. И опять же не понятьно что с файлами иконки и десктоп делать.

Comment: В итоге просто переписал Makefile, а иконки, что с иконками делать? 
ничего не могу понять. Почему-то именно для пакетов deb это какая-то особенная болячка так понимаю.. до этого делал rpm, и для arch linux - вообще проблем не было

Comment: Переписал Makefile ... но уже папку usr/bin он не может создать. Бред какой-то. Использовал команду: dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot

Comment: Может надо писать sudo dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot? раз он не может создать /usr/bin . Какой тогда смысл fakeroot?

Comment: Я как раз DISTDIR и использовал в файле 'rules': $(MAKE) install DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin. Возможно я не там install написал, сейчас попробую $(MAKE)  DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin install.

Comment: У меня в Makefile прописано: -$(QINSTALL_PROGRAM) $(QMAKE_TARGET) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/bin/$(QMAKE_TARGET). Сейчас в rules написал просто $(MAKE) install, пишет то же самое: "Ошибка копирования simplest_studio в /usr/bin/simplest_studio: Невозможно создать /usr/bin/simplest_studio для вывода."

Comment: зачем вы вызываете программу make внутри файла rules? зачем вы вообще всё это в нём понаписали?

Comment: Сейчас мне наконец удалось создать рабочий пакет (добавил в ответ внизу) Надеюсь, что такой метод не разрушит систему.

Comment: Вот что написали мне на одном из англоязычных сайтов по этому поводу, но как обычно они это делают - загадками, чтобы оставить интригу наверное (перевод): "Не полностью указав пути команд install и mkdir, вы просите, чтобы вас взломали. Никогда не доверяй пути. Никогда." Расшифровывать отказываются наотрез просто.

Answer (score 0):

```
install: build
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_installdirs
mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin
install -m 0755 simplest_studio $(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin
mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/share/applications
mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
install -m 0644 simplest-studio.desktop $(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/share/applications
install -m 0644 simplest-studio.png $(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
```